# Unable to open twitter bootstrap modal after complete ajax request asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
$("#find").click(function () {
    var url = "/Home/SendMessage/" + $(this).val('email');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
                You have just signed up for beta access!!
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the success of ajax request nothing happens have checked through firebug as well.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Have you initialised `#myModal` before calling `show` on it?

Comment: There are no errors on the console

Comment: try   $("#myModal").modal().show();

Comment: @AnkushJain Doesn't work

Comment: first add an alert in success response to check weather respnse is coming in success callback or not ?

Comment: Yes i get an alert message on the success callback

Comment: your code is perfect. Now you need to hit and try. Assure following things, you have modal html present on the page before calling modal's show event and you are not getting any error in console and you have added proper js files alsom